# NetSuite Saved Search criteria formula {activity.assigned} = specific employee

Tags: formula, netsuite, criteria, saved-searches

Have a saved search using a formula(numeric) as criteria checking for 0/1 result. Below is example of functional piece:

```
CASE WHEN {activity.date} >= {today}-90 AND {activity.assigned} = {salesrep} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

We also require looking up a specific sales rep here where we know the employee record. We have tried the below:

```
CASE WHEN {activity.date} >= {today}-90 AND {activity.assigned} = EMPLOYEE_ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Where `EMPLOYEE_ID` = the internalId of the Employee. This yields an error: `Your formula has an error in it. It could resolve to the wrong datatype, use an unknown function, or have a syntax error. Please go back, correct the formula, and re-submit.` This happens with "" surrounding it as well. I believe it's looking for a Sales Rep Object, though no idea how to supply this via the formula input field.

Comment: What's stored in `EMPLOYEE_ID`? I would expect to see something like `{activity.assigned} = '12345'`

Comment: EMPLOYEE_ID is just a placeholder for this post, I have tried it as `12345` and `'12345'` formats per your example and both throw the same error. When tested it was the actual internalId for the employee desired.

Answer (score 2):

Use parts of the formula in results to see what is being returned. For an Activity returning {Assigned} is not numeric but text of the name (entityid / EMPLOYEE ID) , ex `E55 Doe, Jane`.

```
case when {assigned} = 'E44 Doe, Jane' then 1 else 0 end
```